# Clicking a link using Selenium Python Library

Tags: python, selenium

How could I click the link highlighted in the attached image using python selenium library, i have tried everything (most attempts shown below), but all not working.

note in the attached picture the element tree.

[image]

Page code (link in question is the last link in the code below:

```
<HEAD>
<TITLE> Constructor Self Service</TITLE>
</HEAD>


<script type="text/javascript">
......
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="/global/res/themes/corporate/css/style3.css"
 type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="/global/res/javascript/horizontal_subsection_HM_Loader.js"></script>

<link rel=stylesheet href="css/tcss.css" TYPE="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="arrays/aaclib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="arrays/csslib.js"></script>




<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0 width="100%" height="100%" >
<tr><td valign="top">
<form name="mainForm" action="/TCSSPRODapp/Controller"
 method="POST" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="command">
<input type="hidden" name="page">
<input type="hidden" name="menuIndex">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="pageToken"
 value=679>
<input type="hidden" name="isInternal"
 value=false>



<body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0"
 marginheight="0">
<!--begin global header--><!--Don't place any other HTML code on this line!!-->
<script language="javascript" src="/global/javascript/head_array.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var v6=0;
if(typeof hmVisi!="undefined"&&typeof sectionId!="undefined" )v6=1;
if(v6)document.write('</head><body bgcolor="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onLoad="TEL_onLoad()">');

function alertUser() {
    if(confirm("Warning: Any unsaved data would be lost.\rDo you want to Continue?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/global/css/gwy_hed.css" type="text/css">
<a name="top"></a>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" valign="top"><a href="http://telstra.com/?tR=1"><img src="/global/images/telstra_logo2.gif" width="85" height="85" border="0" alt="telstra.com"></a></td>
        <td align="right" class="ap1"><span class="hd1"><a href="javascript:toggleAccessibility()"><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="1" height="37" border="0" alt="press enter now to toggle the accessibile text mode of this page" align="absmiddle"></a>
        <a href="http://telstra.com/?tR=1">Telstra Homepage</a> | <a href="http://www.telstra.com.au/contact/?tR=1">Contact Us</a> | <a href="http://search.telstra.com/">Search</a><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="12" height="1" alt=""></span></td>
        <td width="50%" class="ap1"><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="1" height="57" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hd3">
    <!--<td><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="500" height="2" alt=""></td>-->
        <td colspan=50 width="100%"><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="100" height="2" alt=""></td>
        <td><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="1" height="2" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><img src="/global/images/gwy_grad.gif" width="328" height="6" alt=""></td>
        <td class="hd4"><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="1" height="1" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 class="hd5" nowrap><NOBR>
    <table cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1 border=0>
  <tr>
   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:MODIFY:START -->
    <!--<td rowspan=3 class="hd5" nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="15" height="10" alt="" align="top">Telstra Contractor Self Service<img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="25" height="1" alt="" align="top"></td>-->
    <td rowspan=4 class="hd5" nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="5" height="10" alt="" align="top">Telstra Constructor Self Service<img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="5" height="1" alt="" align="top"></td>
   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:MODIFY:END -->
    <TD nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="10" height="12"></TD>
    <TD nowrap></TD>
    <TD nowrap></TD>
   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:START -->
   <!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: start-->
    <!--<TD nowrap></TD>-->
    <!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: start-->
   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:END -->
   <!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: start-->
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:#99ccff;">
   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:START -->

    <TD class=button>
     <a class=button style="text-decoration:none"
     title="AMCO"
     href="javascript:doCommand('doWidebandWorkSummary')"
     onmousemove="window.status='View Work Summary'"
     onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus">
     AMCO</a>
    </TD>

   <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:END -->
    <TD nowrap style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD>
    <TD class=button nowrap>
     <a class=button style="text-decoration:none"
     title="View Inbox"
     href="javascript:doCommand('doInboxStat')"
     onmousemove="window.status='View Inbox'"
     onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus">
     <NOBR>Inbox 0</NOBR></a>
    </TD>
    <TD class=button>
     <a class=button style="text-decoration:none"
     title="View Outbox"
     href="javascript:doCommand('doOutboxStat')"
     onmousemove="window.status='View Outbox'"
     onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus">
     <NOBR>Outbox 0</NOBR></a>
    </TD>

    <!--Start : IPaC Stage II Drop1 : Refresh button added-->
    <TD class=button>
     <a class=button style="text-decoration:none"
     title="Refresh Inbox and Outbox"
     href="javascript:doCommand('doInboxOutboxRefresh')"
     onmousemove="window.status='Refresh Inbox and Outbox'"
     onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus"
     onclick="return alertUser()">
     <NOBR>Refresh</NOBR></a>
    </TD>
    <!--End : IPaC Stage II Drop1-->

    <TD nowrap style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD>
    <TD class=button nowrap>
     <a class=button style="text-decoration:none"
     title="Display TCSS help"
     href="javascript:loadHelpWindow()"
     onmousemove="window.status='Display TCSS help'"
     onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus">
     <NOBR>Help</NOBR></a>
    </TD>
      <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:START -->
   <!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: start-->
<!--<TD nowrap width="151" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD>-->
       <!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: end-->
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <TD nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="38" height="12"></TD>
    <!--Start : IPaC Stage II Drop1 : Display message if refresh didnt occur-->
    <TD nowrap style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD>

         <TD nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="38" height="12"></TD>
         <TD nowrap style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD></tr>
         <tr>
         <TD nowrap><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="38" height="12"></TD>
         <TD nowrap style="background-color:#ffffff;"></TD>
         </tr>
        <!--<TD nowrap></TD>-->
       <!--<TD nowrap></TD>-->
       <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:START -->
        <!--<TD nowrap></TD>-->
       <!-- AMCO-WORKFLOW:ADD:END -->

    <!--End : IPaC Stage II Drop1-->
  </tr>
  </table>

  </NOBR>
  </td>

    </tr>
</table>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

<!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: changed from 100% to 15 % start-->
var s='<table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td class="siteletTitleTab"><img src="/global/images/sin.gif" width="1" height="3" alt=""></td></tr></table>';
<!--5.14.01 Anand Changes: changed from 100% to 15 % end-->
if(v6)document.write(s);
</script>
<!--end global header--><!--Don't place any other HTML code on this line!!-->





<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr class="">
   <td width="100%" rowspan="2" align=right>

  </td>
<TD>
  <INPUT type="hidden" name="internalConstructor" size=10 value="false"> </TD>
</tr>
</table>

<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100%>
<tr><td colspan=50 class=sitelettitletab>
<img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=0 height=3>
</td></tr><tr class=sitelettitletab>

<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doCommand("doFrontPage")' onmousemove="window.status='Home Page'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='Home Page'>Home Page</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doCommand("doTransmittalsInbox")' onmousemove="window.status='My TCSS'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='My TCSS'>My TCSS</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=siteactivetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=siteactivetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=5 height=20></td><td class=siteactivetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tick.gif width=8 height=9>&nbsp;<a class=siteactivetabnav onmousemove="window.status='Work Under Contract'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus">Work Under Contract</a></td><td align=right class=siteactivetabnav  valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doCommand("doGenDocSearch")' onmousemove="window.status='Documents'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='Documents'>Documents</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doCommand("doAssetSearch")' onmousemove="window.status='Reference Library'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='Reference Library'>Reference Library</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doCommand("doAbout")' onmousemove="window.status='Support'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='Support'>Support</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=3 height=1></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_left_inactive.gif width=8 height=20></td><td class=sitetabnav valign=middle align=center nowrap><a class=sitetabnav href='javascript:doLogout()' onmousemove="window.status='Close TCSS'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" title='Close TCSS'>Close TCSS</a></td><td align=right class=sitetabnav valign=top><img src=/global/res/themes/corporate/images/tab_right_inactive.gif width=8 height=20>
<td width=100%><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=1 height=1></td></tr><tr><td colspan=50><img src=/global/res/images/sin.gif width=0 height=2></td></tr></table>

<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0 width=100%><tr><td>
<img src='/global/res/images/sin.gif' width=1 height=3></td></tr><tr class=sitetabnav><td>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0><tr><script type='text/javascript'>
TEL_horizontalSubsectionNav('corporate')
</script><td width=100%>&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>



<table cellspacing=10 cellpadding=0 border=0 width="100%">
<tr><td valign=top width="100%">





<TABLE border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
<TR><TD bgcolor=#99ccff>
<TABLE cellspacing=2 cellpadding=0 border=0 width=100%>
<TR><TD bgcolor=#F1F8FE>
 <TABLE border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
 <TR><TD colspan=2 height=1 bgcolor=#F1F8FE></TD>
 <TD rowspan=3><IMG border=0 src='images/corner.jpg'></TD>
 </TR><TR><TD><IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 src='images/whitedot.gif'></TD>
 <TD class='groupboxheader'>&nbsp;&nbsp;WUC CSA -  Scope Variation - Site & Financial Details &nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR></TABLE>


<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="3" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
  <TD CLASS="label" WIDTH="20%">Contract Number:</TD>
  <TD WIDTH="25%" CLASS="fieldlabel">20003171</TD>
  <TD CLASS="label" WIDTH="20%">Separable Portion:</TD>
  <TD WIDTH="25%" CLASS="fieldlabel">30056120</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD CLASS="label">Work Order:</TD>
  <TD CLASS="fieldLabel">1</TD>
  <TD CLASS="label">CSA Number:</TD>
  <TD CLASS="fieldLabel">4117298</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD CLASS="label">Current CSA Status:</TD>
  <TD class="fieldLabel">
     Draft</TD>
  <TD CLASS="label">Initiated By:</TD>
  <TD CLASS="fieldlabel">CONSTRUCTOR</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD CLASS="label">Issue Number:</TD>
  <TD CLASS="fieldlabel">1</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

  </TD>
 </TR>
 </TABLE>
 </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
function showQuote(sequenceNo) {
    var f = document.mainForm;
    switch (parseInt(sequenceNo)) {
    case 10001:
        f.command.value = "doCsaViewPSDetails";
        break;
    case 10002:
        f.command.value = "doCsaViewDRDetails";
        break;
    case 10003:
        f.command.value = "doCsaViewLSDetails";
        break;
    default:
        f.sequenceNo.value = sequenceNo;
        f.command.value = "doCsaViewDIDetails";
    }
    doSubmit(f);
}

function showMaterialQuote(sequenceNo) {
    var f = document.mainForm;
    f.sequenceNo.value = sequenceNo;
    f.command.value = "doCsaViewMatDetails";
    doSubmit(f);
}
//NDCG:For Link to Non Catalogued material screen
//NDCG:Add:Start
function showNonCatMaterialQuote(sequenceNo) {
    var f = document.mainForm;
    f.command.value = "doCsaViewMatExDetails";
    f.sequenceNo.value = sequenceNo;
    doSubmit(f);
}
//NDCG:ADD:End
</SCRIPT>

<INPUT type="hidden" name="sequenceNo">
<BR>

<TABLE border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" class="table" width="100%">
<TR align="middle">
  <TD rowspan="2" class=colHeader>Type</TD>
  <TD colspan="3" class=colHeader>TCSS Calculated</TD>
  <TD colspan="3" class=colHeader>Quoted</TD>
  <TD colspan="3" class=colHeader>Approved</TD>
  <TD rowspan="2" class=colHeader>View</TD>
</TR>
<TR align="middle">
  <TD class=colHeader>Value</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>GST</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>Price</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>Value</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>GST</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>Price</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>Value</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>GST</TD>
  <TD class=colHeader>Price</TD>
</TR>


<TR>
  <TD class=cell>1. PENRITH - Generic Land & Building - Project</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD class=cell align="center" nowrap>
     <A HREF="javascript:showQuote('1')"><IMG SRC="/global/res/images/view_white.gif" width=44 height=18 onmousemove="window.status='View Item'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" ALT="View Item" BORDER=0></A>
     <A HREF="javascript:showMaterialQuote(1)"><IMG SRC=/global/res/images/material.gif width=16 height=16 border=0 onmousemove="window.status='Catalogued Material'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" alt='Catalogued Material'></A>
     <A HREF="javascript:showNonCatMaterialQuote(1)"><IMG SRC=/global/res/images/material.gif width=16 height=16 border=0 onmousemove="window.status='Non Catalogued Material'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" alt='Non Catalogued Material'></A>
  </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD class=cell>Daywork Rates</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD class=cell align="center" nowrap>
     <A HREF="javascript:showQuote('10002')"><IMG SRC="/global/res/images/view_white.gif" width=44 height=18 onmousemove="window.status='View Item'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" ALT="View Item" BORDER=0></A>


  </TD>
</TR>

<TR>
  <TD class=cell>Lump Sums</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD nowrap class=rightcell>$0.00</TD>
  <TD class=cell align="center" nowrap>
     <A HREF="javascript:showQuote('10003')"><IMG SRC="/global/res/images/view_white.gif" width=44 height=18 onmousemove="window.status='View Item'" onmouseout="window.status=window.defaultStatus" ALT="View Item" BORDER=0></A>


  </TD>
</TR>
```

Attempts:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='javascript:showQuote('10003')']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href="javascript:showQuote('10003')"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('showQuote('10003')').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[href^=javascript:showQuote('10003')]').click()
driver.execute_script('showQuote('10003')')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes to make it work:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[href='javascript:showQuote(\\'10003\\')']").click()
```

Or with a literal string:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(r"[href='javascript:showQuote(\'10003\')']").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried by using xpath something like below

```
   //tbody/tr[5]/td[11]/a/img
```

i know taking positions of tr and td like 5, 11 is not appropriate if they go on changing. but try once to see is it able to click or not.

You can try like this

```
  //a[starts-with(@href, 'javascript:showQuote') and contains(@href, '10003')]
```

If you are using firefox browser then use firebug with firepath add-on to check if it is fetching required unique element or not.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: not too good with path, in this instance it is complicated? any help please

Comment: is there a calculator online for this :)